# PayPal Buy Now Button - Verify payment was submitted

Tags: paypal

Here's the workflow:

1. User submits cart
2. Redirected to PayPal to pay
3. Submit payment
4. Wait for notify_url notification to mark the transaction as "Completed"

At what point would I mark the transaction as "Processing"? I don't want to do it before 2 in case the user closes their browser. I don't want to wait until 4 in case PayPal is delayed. Ideally there would be a callback on payment submission, or a way to force a redirect after submission. What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider using something like Express Checkout.  This way, you know exactly when the payment has been processed, because you have to run an API call to actually process the payment.  If the payment ends up being delayed for some reason (for example, buyer paid with eCheck), you can still use IPN to be notified when the payment actually clears.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/